# Implementing Gutenberg RichText onSplit / onReplace

Tags: block-editor

I need an unordered list, but with options selected for each list item. To achieve this I've created a custom block called icon-list which is a `ul` element with InnerBlocks, which allows only my custom icon-list-item block as a child. My icon-list-item block is just a RichText element with `tagName: li` and some controls. This all works fine, but currently pressing the enter key adds a line break to the current icon-list-item block - what I'd really like is for the enter key to insert a new icon-list-item block. Similarly pressing the backspace key when at the start of a icon-list-item block should remove that block - the exact same functionality of the core/list block.

I've had a dig through the Gutenberg docs and source and found that I need to implement the onSplit and onReplace properties for my RichText element, but it's not clear to me how I actually do this. So far I have:

```
el(RichText, {
    tagName     : 'li',
    className   : 'icon--' + props.attributes.icon,
    value       : props.attributes.content,
    placeholder : props.attributes.placeholder,
    onChange    : function(value) {
        props.setAttributes({ content: value })
    },
    onSplit     : function(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return createBlock('tutti/icon-list-item');
        }

        return createBlock('tutti/icon-list-item', {
            ...props.attributes,
            content: value,
        }
    },
    onReplace   : function() {
        // something
    }
})
```

... obviously I'm completely lost when it comes to the onReplace function. Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try setting `multiline` property of `RichText` to true? This should insert new element instead of inserting break line.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. I just was browsing looking for something else. But I would try something like this:

```
onReplace: function() {
   var myID    = props.clientId;
   wp.data.dispatch('core/block-editor').removeBlock(myID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented a list-like element which behaves like a native list element. I did this because of a deprecation notice in the `RichText` component. The `multiline` property, which could be used to make this kind of behaviour work, [will be removed in version 6.3](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/4faba613bc30df69618a191ebabb63fa01787599/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/index.js#L120) and it is advised to use `InnerBlocks` instead.

```js
const blockSettings = {
  /**
    * @param attributes Attribute object of blockA
    * @param attributesToMerge Attribute object of blockB
    *
    * @returns {} Attribute object after the merge
    */
  merge: (attributes, attributesToMerge) => {
    return {
      content: (attributes.content || "") +
               (attributesToMerge.content || ""),
    }
  },
  edit: (props) => {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
      // Define blog poperties
    })

    return el(RichText, {
      ...blockProps, // Block properties not necessary for this example
      identifier: "content", // This is needed to prevent an error message
      onSplit: (value, isOriginal) => {
        let newAttributes = {}

        if (isOriginal || value) {
          newAttributes = {
            ...props.attributes,
            content: value,
          }
        }

        const block = createBlock("custom/my-list--item", newAttributes)

        // Set first element's clientId to original clientId to preserve it
        if (isOriginal) {
          block.clientId = props.clientId
        }

        return block
      },
      // Functions provided in blockProps by useBlockProps()
      onReplace: props.onReplace,
      onMerge: props.mergeBlocks,
      onRemove: props.onRemove,
    })
  }
}
```

The code is borrowed from Gutenberg's own `core/paragraph` block ([/packages/block-library/src/paragraph](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/paragraph)).

The `props`-object you receive from `useBlockProps`-function imported from `wp.editor` in your `edit`-function already contains functions for `onReplace`, `onRemove` and `mergeBlocks` for the `onMerge`-event.
Source: [/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/edit.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/edit.js#L152) line 152

In addition to the `edit`-function, you have to declare a `merge`-function in your block's settings. It will receive the attributes of both blocks and return the attributes of the merged block. If you don't declare `merge`, the merge will fail without an error message.
Source: [/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/index.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/index.js#L43) line 43

The RichText also needs an `identifier`-prop. Without it, an error is thrown.
Source: [/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/edit.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/edit.js#L127) line 127

The `onSplit`-function sets the `clientId` of the original list-item to the value of `props.clientId`, because `onSplit` replaces the original block and therefore generates a new id.

```js
// Pseudo code
originalBlockA = {
  clientId: "A",
}

const { blockA, blockB } = onSplit(originalBlockA)

blockA.clientId == "B"
blockB.clientId == "C"
```

Source: [/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/edit.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/edit.js#L134) line 134

The functionality itself is kind of documented in the [README.md](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/4faba613bc30df69618a191ebabb63fa01787599/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md), but the crucial part, the `identifier`-property and `merge`-function are missing.

The need for a `merge`-function can be found in the `core/block-editor`-data-store: [/packages/block-editor/src/store/actions.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-editor/src/store/actions.js#L1025) line 1025

The need for an `identifier`-property is more or less documented in [/packages/block-editor/src/store/selectors.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/4faba613bc30df69618a191ebabb63fa01787599/packages/block-editor/src/store/selectors.js#L341). It is used in [/packages/block-editor/src/store/actions.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-editor/src/store/actions.js#L1057) on [line 1057](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-editor/src/store/actions.js#L1057) and the `attributeKey` is checked on [line 1073](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/8af389fc653690ed201bf5fe864ec82d99a57775/packages/block-editor/src/store/actions.js#L1073).